# Call matching methods from inherited classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, methods, multiple-inheritance

what is the best method to call matching methods from a single class that inherit 3 other base classes with same method name? i want to call those methods from a single call, don't know if it's even possible

```
template<typename T>
class fooBase()
{
    void on1msTimer();
    /* other methods that make usage of the template */
}

class foo
    : public fooBase<uint8_t>
    , public fooBase<uint16_t>
    , public fooBase<float>
{
    void onTimer()
    {
         // here i want to call the on1msTimer() method from each base class inherited 
         // but preferably without explicitly calling on1msTimer method for each base class
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to call three different functions, you *have to* tell the compiler which three functions you want to call.

Comment: One option is for all the base classes to inherit virtually from an event dispatcher, and register their own implementation with the dispatcher during construction.  Then the most-derived class can invoke the list of functions via the dispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with one call to get all the three member functions at once. Imagine these member functions would return something else than void:  which return value would you expect ?!

If you want to call the `on1msTimer()` of all the three base classes, you need to call these explicitly:

```
void onTimer()
{
     fooBase<float>::on1msTimer();
     fooBase<uint8_t>::on1msTimer();
     fooBase<uint16_t>::on1msTimer();
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/uLjJIW)